# Laravel 8 Redis cache only triggering when running query via Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm working in a Laravel 8 project that's being used as an API for my backend. I'm using MongoDB as my database and a Redis server.

I've configured Redis in my project using `predis` and can confirm that the cache does store and retrieve correctly, but what I've recently noticed is a strange behaviour where the cache isn't storing at all, I know this because the request to query 10 million rows takes 8 seconds each time and should be a few hundred.

If I make the request through my browser to a single `Application` then any requests beyond the first for half hour should be cached and quick, but are all slow, if I then run a `Application` find in tinker and then load up my view, it's cached because it's loading instantly?

What's going on here, and what might I be missing from my code?

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Application  $application
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Application $application)
{
    $application = Cache::store('redis')->remember("application:$application", Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30), function () use ($application) {
        return Application::with([
            'payday', 'response', 'apiLinks'
        ])->find($application)->first();
    });

    return response()->json([
        'application' => $application
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: `"application:$application"` will coerce the application model to a string which may have unexpected results (unless you implemented the `__toString()` method) like e.g. caching against the object hash code which changes on each request. I would suggest you cache on the application identifier

Comment: What is the cache env set to ?

Comment: @apokryfos do you mean just use the id of the application?

Comment: @mrhn cache driver is `CACHE_DRIVER` set to `file` because I'm using `store` as redis

Comment: oh didn't see, what happens if you use the application->id instead of just $application?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you seem to be using [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) here but you intend to cache the model. Bound models are not cached. Change your code to:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $application
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($application)
{
    $application = Cache::store('redis')->remember("application:$application", Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30), function () use ($application) {
        return Application::with([
            'payday', 'response', 'apiLinks'
        ])->find($application)->first();
    });

    return response()->json([
        'application' => $application
    ], 200);
}
```

Just as a reminder if you do `Route::get('application/{application}', function (Application $application) { ... });` i.e. you provide a type in the function definition, Laravel will attempt to retrieve the model given by the route parameter automatically (this is, as I mentioned above, is called [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding)). However since you want to cache the model then you should not allow this to happen.